# Somfy WT motor must not be driven by a solid-state relay or triac relay?

Tags: motor, ac, induction-motor, solid-state-relay

I came across this line in the installation / operating guidelines of a comfy (blinds) motor:

> The drive must not be driven by a solid-state relay or triac relay.

Would there be any technical reason why this shouldn't be allowed? (see [installation](https://service.somfy.com/downloads/no_v5/shortmanual_j4_wt_protect.pdf) / [operating](https://www.stobag.com/fileadmin/files/dokumente/automatisierung_steuersysteme/anleitungen_motoren/STOBAG_Ansteuerrichtlinien_DE_EN_FR.pdf) guidelines)

These blind motors can detect when they are frozen or when there is an obstruction. Thus, when they feel resistance they won't try to move up/down.
Could it be that when I connect then to SSR this would interfere with this function?

I currently have it working with 100nF and 100 ohm snubbers over both directions of the motor. (These are 0.5A/230V reversible motors.)

Comment: What's the motor rating in watts or amps? I suspect that an SSR's snubber may give enough leakage to cause trouble. Can you measure the coil resistance?

Comment: There are different versions see [technical data](https://www.somfy-profesional.es/documents/1933827/70558287/Datasheet_Ilmo_50_WT_Range1R0.pdf/401a714d-405c-4ee9-a813-efc24eb690b2?version=1.0). I've measure the current at 0.44A. So it's either the 90 or 120W version. I've measured  1 MOhm from one direction wire to the neutral wire, I doubt that's the coils resistance though, as it seems high to me.

Comment: @Transistor I've also noticed that if I put the snubbers across the SSRs instead of the motor, the motor will not move. The operation guidelines state: "the voltage of the other direction of rotation may not exceed 55Vrms". Maybe this is part of the reason why SSRs should't be used?